# How to pass list of TouchPoints from QML to C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I'm using a MultiPointTouchArea and want to pass the list of touchpoints to C++ side whenever onPressed, onReleased or onUpdated is triggered.

This is what I have tried without success:

QML:

```
MultiPointTouchArea  {
  minimumTouchPoints: 1
  maximumTouchPoints: 2

  touchPoints: [
    TouchPoint { id: touch1 },
    TouchPoint { id: touch2 }
  ]

  onPressed: {
    myCPlusPlusClass.onPressed(touchPoints)
  }
}
```

C++:

```
void myCPlusPlusClass::onPressed(const QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint>& list) 
{
  // Do something
}
```

I have registered QListQTouchEvent::TouchPoint as a metatype like so:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint>>("QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint>");
```

I don't get any errors however the list is just i nullptr or similar on the C++ side.

My second best option would be to pass the TouchPoints individually (not in a list).

Is this possible to solve?
If not, what are my options to pass all information from a TouchPoint to C++ side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a way could be to pass to C++ an easily parsable 'report' about the component state. Dunno right now which properties there are in TouchPoint(s), but presumably dumping them to text seems easily feasible (maybe using Array.join). Then parse back from C++ and use that data.

Comment: Yes, absolutely an option. Thanks! It feels weird though that it wouldn't be possible to pass TouchPoints from Qml to C++ since Qml has its TouchPoint and C++ has QTouchPoint. But maybe it's not "normal behaviour" to pass this kind of data.

Comment: It's surely possible, but the gory details are outside my view right now :( I've found working with metadata not the easiest thing ever, specially at QML/Qt C++ interface

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist to use multi-touch from C++, you could simply intercept the touch events on the C++ side and not bother with the `MultiPointTouchArea` whatsoever, I mean if that is literally all you need it for.

It is quite the stretch to expect this code to work, the list of types that are implicitly converted back and forth between QML and C++ do not include touch points, much less lists of such.

A saner approach would include an interface that would receive the relevant input information only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is QML keeps track of a certain state and when pressing/panning/pinching etc. I want to perform different tasks. 
QML-state-1 + press->release should place a pointer.
QML-state-2 + press->release should start a measurement.
Panning while in QML-state-1 should not place a pointer. Right now C++ actually intercepts the events but the complexity gets very high when C++ should keep track of the QML state, hence want to pass a command + a position from QML to C++. It's a bit difficult to explain a application just in words. But once again, thanks for the advice.

Comment: To shed some more light on the problem. QML handles all user input and then there is a C++/OpenGl graphics engine which renders into a OpenGl window. The C++ backend also handle all navigation whereas I have to pass all events to the backend.

Comment: Then simply only pass over the relevant input data based on the current state in QML. Easy peasy. You simply need a more featured interface to C++. Since that's user input, it is not like QML performance is gonna bottleneck you, so you really don't have to do all the input reasoning in C++, therefore you don't need to pass the original input points in full.